# VBA code works in a workbook but not in PERSONAL.XLSB

Tags: excel, vba

I have created VBA code on a workbook that sends each worksheet in that workbook as an attachment to a specified email recipient. It works great. I want this code to be available for use on other worksheets so I added the working code to my PERSONAL.XLSB. When I copy that same code to PERSONAL.XLSB it does not work. Not even on the original worksheet that it had worked on because I moved the code to Personal.XLSB

I have other macros in Personal.xlsb that work so I know I'm utilizing my personal macro workbook correctly.

```
Sub Mail_Every_Worksheet()

'Updateby ExtendOffice
  Dim xWs As Worksheet
  Dim xWb As Workbook
  Dim xFileExt As String
  Dim xFileFormatNum As Long
  Dim xTempFilePath As String
  Dim xFileName As String
  Dim xOlApp As Object
  Dim xMailObj As Object


  On Error Resume Next
  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .EnableEvents = False
  End With

  xTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
  If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    xFileExt = ".xls": xFileFormatNum = -4143
  Else
    xFileExt = ".xlsm": xFileFormatNum = 52
  End If

  Set xOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If xWs.Range("S2").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
      xWs.Copy
      Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook
      xFileName = xWs.Name & " - " _
                   & VBA.Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, VBA.InStr(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & " "
      Set xMailObj = xOlApp.CreateItem(0)
      xWb.Sheets.Item(1).Range("S2").Value = ""
      With xWb
        .SaveAs xTempFilePath & xFileName & xFileExt, FileFormat:=xFileFormatNum
        With xMailObj



        'specify the CC, BCC, Subject, Body below
            .To = xWs.Range("S2").Value
            .CC = xWs.Range("S4").Value & ";RSimmons@oldmutual.com;SMfeka@oldmutual.com;MBehari@oldmutual.com;LFurlong@oldmutual.com;KPerumal2@oldmutual.com;IDeVries@oldmutual.com;BEllis@OLDMUTUAL.COM;AMuller4@oldmutual.com"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Name & " for " & xWs.Range("S1")
            .Body = "Dear " & xWs.Range("S3")
            .Attachments.Add xWb.FullName


            .Display
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
      Set xMailObj = Nothing
      Kill xTempFilePath & xFileName & xFileExt
    End If
  Next
  Set xOlApp = Nothing
  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .EnableEvents = True
  End With
End Sub
```

I tried changing

ThisWorkbook.Name to ActiveWorkbook.Name
and
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets to ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheets

but then it only generates one email and closes

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ... and why do you even want to do this? Personal.xslb is a template, it should not be used as a regular Excel file.

Comment: @Dominique `PERSONAL.xlsb` is usually used hidden and opens with Excel. When you click `Macros` on the developer tab i.e. open the `Macro` dialog, all macros from `PERSONAL.xlsb` get listed so you can easily select which one to run (usually on the active workbook). That's not the case with an Add-in (a `.xlam` file). Read [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790) about the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Variables to Distinguish Between Workbooks (Send Emails)

- `ThisWorkbook` is a reference to the workbook containing this code which is `PERSONAL.xlsb` so it has no place in your code.
- Use `ActiveWorkbook` instead. The problem arises when you copy a sheet, most often, the newly created workbook becomes the (new) `ActiveWorkbook` (safer is `Workbook(Workbooks.Count)`), then you cannot safely refer to the initial `ActiveWorkbook`. Therefore use a variable to reference the initial `ActiveWorkbook`:

  ```
  Dim swb as Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
  ```

  and a different one to reference the new workbooks: `dwb`.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub MailEveryWorksheet()
    
    Dim MutualMails(): MutualMails = Array( _
        "RSimmons@oldmutual.com", "SMfeka@ oldmutual.com", _
        "MBehari@ oldmutual.com", "LFurlong@ oldmutual.com", _
        "KPerumal2@ oldmutual.com", "IDeVries@ oldmutual.com", _
        "BEllis@ oldmutual.com", "AMuller4@ oldmutual.com")
    
    Dim dTempFolderPath As String: dTempFolderPath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String, dFileFormat As Long
    
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        dFileExtension = ".xls": dFileFormat = -4143
    Else
        dFileExtension = ".xlsm": dFileFormat = 52
    End If
    
    If ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = swb.Name
    
    Dim DotPosition As Long: DotPosition = InStrRev(swbName, ".")
    
    Dim sBaseName As String
    
    If DotPosition = 0 Then
        sBaseName = swbName
    Else
        sBaseName = Left(swbName, DotPosition - 1)
    End If
    
    Dim olApp As Object: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet
    Dim dFileName As String, dFilePath As String
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        If sws.Range("S2").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            sws.Copy
            Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
            dFileName = sws.Name & " - " & sBaseName & " " ' why the space?
            dFilePath = dTempFolderPath & dFileName & dFileExtension
            With dwb
                .Sheets(1).Range("S2").Value = ""
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite, no confirmation
                    .SaveAs dFilePath, dFileFormat
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
            With olApp.CreateItem(0)
                'specify the CC, BCC, Subject, Body below
                .To = sws.Range("S2").Value
                .CC = sws.Range("S4").Value & ";" & Join(MutualMails, ";")
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = swbName & " for " & sws.Range("S1")
                .Body = "Dear " & sws.Range("S3")
                .Attachments.Add dFilePath
                .Display
                '.Send
            End With
            Kill dFilePath
        End If
    Next sws
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    MsgBox "Emails sent.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Small correction: You should use `InStrRev` when looking for the file extension. Filenames (and foldernames) may contains dots.

Comment: Nice catch. Never gave it a thought. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you for your assistance

I get the following error when I run the code above that you recommended:

sBaseName = Left(swbName, DotPosition) - 1

Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you for all your help. I figured out the error above and the code works perfectly now `sBaseName=Left(swbName, DotPosition-1)`

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I see you figured it out. Well done. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

`Sub MailEveryWorksheet()

```
Dim MutualMails(): MutualMails = Array( _
    "RSimmons@oldmutual.com", "SMfeka@ oldmutual.com", _
    "MBehari@ oldmutual.com", "LFurlong@ oldmutual.com", _
    "KPerumal2@ oldmutual.com", "IDeVries@ oldmutual.com", _
    "BEllis@ oldmutual.com", "AMuller4@ oldmutual.com")

Dim dTempFolderPath As String: dTempFolderPath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

Dim dFileExtension As String, dFileFormat As Long

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    dFileExtension = ".xls": dFileFormat = -4143
Else
    dFileExtension = ".xlsm": dFileFormat = 52
End If

If ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open

Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim swbName As String: swbName = swb.Name

Dim DotPosition As Long: DotPosition = InStrRev(swbName, ".")

Dim sBaseName As String

If DotPosition = 0 Then
    sBaseName = swbName
Else
    sBaseName = Left(swbName, DotPosition-1)
End If

Dim olApp As Object: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Dim dwb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet
Dim dFileName As String, dFilePath As String

For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
    If sws.Range("S2").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
        sws.Copy
        Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        dFileName = sws.Name & " - " & sBaseName & " " ' why the space?
        dFilePath = dTempFolderPath & dFileName & dFileExtension
        With dwb
            .Sheets(1).Range("S2").Value = ""
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite, no confirmation
                .SaveAs dFilePath, dFileFormat
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        With olApp.CreateItem(0)
            'specify the CC, BCC, Subject, Body below
            .To = sws.Range("S2").Value
            .CC = sws.Range("S4").Value & ";" & Join(MutualMails, ";")
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = swbName & " for " & sws.Range("S1")
            .Body = "Dear " & sws.Range("S3")
            .Attachments.Add dFilePath
            .Display
            '.Send
        End With
        Kill dFilePath
    End If
Next sws

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox "Emails sent.", vbInformation
```

End Sub`